# How to create a smooth black and white texture without jaggies?

Tags: image-processing, random, image, generative-art, rasterize

The following code creates a random black and white texture with ugly jaggies (pixelized "stairs") all around the shapes, because of the `Binarize` command.  I could add a final `Blur` or `GaussianFilter` to remove them, but the result is too blurry.  How can I modify that code to get nice smooth shapes, without bluring it?

```
randomTiles = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomInteger[{0, 1}]}, {n, 1, 1000}];

Binarize[Blur[ListDensityPlot[
   randomTiles,
   InterpolationOrder -> 0,
   Frame -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0,
   ImageSize -> {400, 400}
   ], 10]]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:

[image]

Comment: The simplest thing might be to create the image larger than you need and reduce it using `ImageResize`.

Comment: @SimonWoods, I believe this would be similar to adding a blur to the image.  But I'll try it.

Comment: @SimonWoods, apparently, it doesn't work.  I used 1500 pixels instead of 1024 in the code above, then added ImageResize with {1024, 1024} as new size.  It still gives strong pixelated shapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `ColorFunction -> Graylevel` in `ListDensityPlot` to start from a black and white image, avoiding `Binarize` altogether.
- ask for a much higher number of pixels in your image with `ImageSize`; that alone causes considerable smoothing when you downsize the image;
- for further effect, apply e.g. `MedianFilter` with an appropriate parameter.

```
SeedRandom[1234]
randomTiles = 
  Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomInteger[{0, 1}]}, {n, 1, 1000}];


MedianFilter[#, 5] &@
 ListDensityPlot[
   randomTiles,
   InterpolationOrder -> 0, Frame -> False,
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> {1000, 1000},
   ColorFunction -> GrayLevel
 ]
```

[image: smoother version]

Comment: Oh yes!  This works very nicely, and I can even choose another color scheme with this!  Can you explain more in depth what the MedianFilter is doing, with its option 5?

Comment: @Cham Since a picture is worth a thousand words, particularly in this case, take a look at the results of its usage [in the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MedianFilter.html). The effect is pretty clear to the eye, although I would be hard pressed to put it in words. Technically, `MedianFilter` replaces a pixel's value with the median value of pixels in a neighborhood whose size is controlled by its parameter.

Comment: Ok, I think it's clear.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option using [`Rasterize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html).

```
SeedRandom[1234];
img = Binarize[
   Blur[ListDensityPlot[randomTiles, InterpolationOrder -> 0, 
     Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
     ImageSize -> {1600, 1600}], 40]];
rimg = Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 400, ImageSize -> 400]
ImageDimensions[rimg]
```

[image: Rasterized image]

Comment: Feed that into `MorphologicalComponents[rimg] // Colorize` and you have some high art.